# Intel UHD Graphics driver confusing X and Y display resolution (20.04 & 22.04)

Tags: drivers, display, intel-graphics, display-resolution, display-rotation

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to get it installed on this (formerly Windows 10) device to use as a kiosk.

Device shows Ubuntu desktop in portrait mode on landscape setting:

[image: Device shows Ubuntu desktop in portrait mode on landscape setting]

When I use the Intel driver, the display confuses the X and Y axis of the touch screen resulting in a 1280x800 touch screen displaying a 800x1280 display that only uses 1/3 of the display surface. No matter what I do with display resolution, rotation or xrandr, I cannot get it to fill the entire display. The device details and output of `neofetch` are shown in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing hardware details and the wrong screen resolution detection]

The output from lshw is as follows:

```
$ lshw -c video
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 605
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:133 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

xrandr yields this output:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 800 x 1280, maximum 16384 x 16384
DSI-1 connected primary 800x1280+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   15360x8640    15.83    28.85  
   7680x4320     15.83    59.99    59.99    59.99  
   5120x2880     59.99    59.99  

[ ... truncated for clarity]
```

If I boot into safe graphics, I can get the full display to be used:

[image: Safe graphics using full display]

I could live with using safe graphics as my kiosk application isn't terribly resource intensive, but when I try to rotate the screen into landscape mode, xrandr fails with an obscure error that I can't find a way around and it stubbornly stays in portrait mode.

```
$ xrandr -o left
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  2 (RRSetScreenConfig)
  Serial number of failed request:  14
  Current serial number in output stream:  14
```

Is there a way to either force the Intel UHD driver to use the entire display or alternatively convince safe graphics to rotate the screen?

Update: I tried running up Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it works correctly.